# Joins in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents with the following structures

```
Shipment_received : 
    {
    Some  header level detail
    "ItemId" : "I1",
    "Quantity" : Q1
    "Vendor" : "V1"
   }

shipment_Ordered :  {
    Some header level details
    "ItemId" : "I2"
    "Quantity" : Q2
    "Vendor":"V1" 
}
```

For a given vendor I want to find the average difference in the Order Quantity and the received quantity. How can this be done using elastic search ?

Comment: Received quantity isn't in your document, which may be an issue. Use aggregations.

Comment: Hi Chris, could you please elaborate on which type of aggregations can be used ? I fell we might require joins and aggregations alone would not suffice

Comment: The avg aggregation with a custom script to return the value of order - received is where I'd start.

Comment: I am pretty new to elastic search. So, I am sorry if this is a very obvious question. But, using scripts is it possible to know the document type after running an aggregation query ?   Talking in pure SQL terms , I would need something like this select avg(ordered.quantity-recv.quantity), itemId, vendor from received, ordered where  ordered.itemId = received.itemId

Comment: What do you mean by "document type"? All documents in ES are JSON.

Comment: I mean whether the quantity is corresponding to "Shipment_ordered" document or "Shipment_received" document

Comment: Well, ES doesn't do joins. You're going to want to do something like aggregating on item ID and vendor, then sub-aggregate your quantities, but your data is ill-formed for this query. You should probably have one document per order which includes both the quantity ordered and received.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have made modifications to model it in the way you suggested.